# default generic design pattern used by in java

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I was asked in an interview

> Which default design pattern used by generics in java ?? or is any
>   design pattern used by generics in java ??"

What is the answer?

Comment: Strange question, are you sure you understood it correctly? Generics are neither a design pattern nor do they use one. On the other hand, many design patterns can be used with generics.

Comment: Template pattern comes to mind.

Comment: I guess they must be referring to "type erasure" as a pattern.

Comment: Thnx for your comments..i am sure they asking same question as i mentioned because i asked them twice.You have any link for "type erasure" and template pattern.

Comment: Generics in Java relates to Polymorphism, but not exactly to a Design Pattern itself.